# Unix: Search and replace in file names

Tags: unix, sed, filenames, regex

Using `sed`, I can search and replace text in a file. Is there a way I can do search and replace of filenames? For example if I have a bunch of files in a folder with names like these:

- foo01
- foo02
- bar001
- bar002

I would like to quickly rename all of the ones starting with foo so that they have 3 digits instead of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for file in foo*
do
  filename=${file%%[0-9]*}
  num=${file##*[^0-9]}
  newnum=$(printf "%03d" $num)
  newfile=${filename}${newnum}
  mv "$file" "$newfile"
done
```

Comment: Wow. What does all of that do?

Comment: @Svish Take a look at the _Advanced Bash Scripting Guide_ http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html

Comment: @KeithB: Don't feel like reading a whole book just to decipher a few lines of script...

Comment: then read this: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22102

Comment: Don't have enough rep to edit myself, but `${f%%` in line 5 should be `${file%%`

Comment: shows that you have actually looked at it. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use [MacPorts](http://macports.org), there is a package called *renameutils*. I've never used it, but from the description, it may be what you want.

> renameutils - tools that make renaming files easier        Description ¶
>
> renameutils contains 5 programs: qmv,
>   qcp, imv, icp, and deurlname
>
> qmv and qcp use the aid of a text
>   editor to create a "plan" that is
>   executed when the file is saved -
>   great for batch moves
>
> imv and icp are interactive programs
>   with GNU readline support
>
> deurlname removes URL encoded
>   characters from a filename
>
> More info at the project's homepage 
>   http://www.nongnu.org/renameutils/

Comment: Interesting. Will have a look at that some time :)

Comment:  Thanks a lot! Finally I found a find/replace in the CLI which is almost as easy as in a GUI file renamer or GUI text editor:

1. `qmv --format=destination-only`.
2. Opens the replacement instructions as a simple temporary text file in `nano` in the single column format.
3. Find/Replace operation in `nano` works interactively like in a GUI editor.
4. You exit and save that temporary file.
5. `qmv? checks that instruction file for consistency and if error free performs the renaming.

Great! 

Comment: As of 2022-12 `renameutils` were available for macOS via the `brew` package manager and on my ARM Linux via `apt`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Perl script that may already be on your system called `rename` or `prename`.

```
rename 's/\d\d$/0$&/' foo*
```

If you run that multiple times it will continue to insert zeros. To prevent that, this version only renames files that end in two digits (preceded by at least one non-digit):

```
rename 's/([^\d])(\d\d)$/${1}0$2/' foo*
```

- `s///` is the substitute command
- `\d` stands for a digit
- `$&` in the first example stands for everything that was matched between the first two slashes (two digits in this case)
- `[^\d]` stands for all characters (`[]`) that are not (`^`) digits (`\d`)
- `${1}` stands for what was matched in the first set of parentheses (a non-digit), the braces set the "1" off from the literal "0"
- `$2` stands for what was matched in the second set of parentheses (two digits), the braces aren't necessary here, but you could use them

Comment: Looks like exactly what I want. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to exist on Mac OS X =/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look `mmv` (should be available for all kinds of Linux but is rarely installed by default).